# The Ubuntu installation is faulty

Tags: ubuntu, software-updates

I have installed the recommended two updates (Ubuntu) to 18.04 and since I can no longer open my writing files (LibreOffice). There is an error message BrokenCount>0 and that the package is corrupted. I tried to fix the error by using the internet in the terminal, but it didn't work.
I tried it with: sudo apt get update, upgrade,dist-upgrade, install ...Today I tried several times >>apt autoremove<< and >>apt --fix-broken install, but it didn't work.
LANG=C[Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig Probieren Sie »apt --fix-broken install«, um dies zu korrigieren. Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten: libmutter-6-0 : Beschädigt: apparmor (< 2.13.3-5~) aber 2.12-4ubuntu5.3 ist installiert libreoffice-calc : Beschädigt: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 ist installiert libreoffice-common : Beschädigt: libreoffice-core (>= 1:6.1~) aber 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 ist installiert Beschädigt: libreoffice-style-breeze (>= 1:6.1~) aber 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 ist installiert Beschädigt: libreoffice-style-galaxy (>= 1:6.1~) aber 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 ist installiert Beschädigt: libreoffice-style-tango (>= 1:6.1~) aber 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8 ist installiert libreoffice-core : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-common (> 1:6.4.7) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 ist installiert libreoffice-draw : Beschädigt: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 ist installiert libreoffice-help-common : Beschädigt: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.3.0) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 ist installiert libreoffice-help-de : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-common (>= 1:6.1.0~) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 ist installiert libreoffice-help-en-us : Hängt ab von: libreoffice-common (>= 1:6.1.0~) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 ist installiert libreoffice-impress : Beschädigt: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 ist installiert libreoffice-math : Beschädigt: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 ist installiert libreoffice-writer : Beschädigt: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) aber 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.13 ist installiert E: Unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten. Versuchen Sie »apt --fix-broken install« ohne Angabe eines Pakets (oder geben Sie eine Lösung an).]Sorry!

Comment: What is the exact text of the error message, and what did you do that resulted in the message?

Comment: What are the exact commands you have tried, and what happened when you tried them? (`sudo apt get update, upgrade,dist-upgrade, install ...` isn't an exact command, it's an approximation)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the new information. Don't put it here in the comments. Remember to mark code as `code` with the `{}` button

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 was EOL 6 months ago - you were due for an upgrade anyway.

Comment: An error occurred, pleas start the package manager from the context menu or run >>apt-get<< in a terminal to investigate the problem. The error messages was: >>Error: BrokenCount>0<<<. This usually means that the dependencies of installed packages cannot be satisfied.

Comment: Sorry, my english is not so good. I need a translater